# Non-object error when iterating object array

Tags: php

I'm trying to loop trough an array of objects and peform some logic [see function]. However, I'm getting an *"Trying to get property of non-object"*-error on the line with the comment. So I checked if it's an object and it's not. When creating the `$product` object and doing a check on `$partners_obj`, the instanceof function tells me it is indeed an Partner object...

So it must be a problem in the iteration. But I don't see whats wrong...

**The Function**

```
function lowest_price_for_product($product) { // $product instanceof Product == true
    $price = null;
    foreach($product->partners_obj as $partner) { // $partner instanceof Partner == false
        if(is_null($price)) {
            $price = $partner->product_price;
        } else {
            if($price > $partner->product_price) {
                $price = $partner->product_price;
            }
        }
    }
    return $price;
}
```

**Product class**

```
class Product {
     public $id;
     public $name;
     public $description;
     public $image;
     public $partners_obj = array();
}
```

**Partner class**

```
class Partner {
    public $id;
    public $name;
    public $partner_url;
    public $image;
    public $product_url;
    public $product_price;
}
```

**var_dump($partner); in foreach loop**

```
array(3) { 
    [0]=> object(Partner)#9 (6) { 
        ["id"]=> string(1) "1" 
        ["name"]=> string(11) "Fun-&-Feest" 
        ["partner_url"]=> string(34) XXX" 
        ["image"]=> string(15) "Fun-&-Feest.png" 
        ["product_url"]=> string(56) "XXX" 
        ["product_price"]=> string(4) "8.50" 
    }
...
```

Comment: How are you putting values into `->partners_obj`?

Comment: try `var_dump($partner);` in your foreach

Comment: you have conception error too, one product have one or many Partner, partner have price for one product, really strange.
Change for one product have one or many PartnerPrice, PartnerPrice is price for this product and this partner

Comment: Conception is as intended.. I've added the var_dump and it seems fine :/

Comment: Or not... `$partner` is the array not the $partner object in the array...

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol I made a mistake when declaring the partners_obj :D

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$product[] = $product->partners_obj;` than `foreach($product as $partner) { //statement }`

Whole function:

`function lowest_price_for_product($product) { // $product instanceof Product == true
        $price = null;
        $product[] = $product->partners_obj;
        foreach($product as $partner) { // $partner instanceof Partner == false
            if(is_null($price)) {
                $price = $partner->product_price;
            } else {
                if($price > $partner->product_price) {
                   $price = $partner->product_price;
                }
            }
        }
        return $price;
    }`